# add user 'name' to posts JSON with Ruby on Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delegates, belongs-to

I have a Posts model which belongs to the User model in my Rails API repo.
I have added a column in the Posts table which is 'username'.
I would like to add the current_user.name to everypost in the username column.

Can I use delegate to add the User who creates the post's Name to the username column on my Post table.

I have already added the user_id as the reference which works.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def as_json(options={})
    super(only: [:description, :created_at, :user_id, :username])
  end
end
```

This is only for use as a API and everytime I access the Post show route I would like the JSON to return the Users name that the posts belongs to in the JSON under :username

Comment: I think the Post table should not contain the `username` attribute but instead ask its associated `User` instance what is its `username`. Why? Because when the post's user changes to another one, you would have to make sure the post's username is changed accordingly. There are several other reasons to not add this username column to Post and just leave it to the user.

Comment: I am only using this as a API and associated user for a post will never change - it is similar to the facebook user / posts model

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind relational databases like you are using it with ActiveRecord is that you don't have to take care of things like "copying" over the user names.

If your database schema says that every **Post belongs to a User** and you can call the User of a Post by calling:

`post.user.username`

The post you are trying to get the user from has to be.

Some good examples that might help you understand this further can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

To get an understanding of how you could build out and structure your Rails API you could start with this guide: https://www.codementor.io/ruby-on-rails/tutorial/creating-simple-api-with-rails

Comment: I'm using rails simply as an api so post.user.username won't work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So you are getting the data from an API and therefore can't access the data over ActiveRecord? Or are you building an API? Maybe consider clarifying the question.

Comment: I am using rails as an api and all the posts data is accessed through a json. I would like the user name which every post belongs to be included in the posts json

Comment: That doesn't stop you from using the relational benefits of ActiveRecord. In fact there is API functionality included in Rails Core: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) instead of override `as_json`.
Look at this article : https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'
bundle install
rails g serializer post
rails g serializer user
```

Adds the attributes / relations that you want to expose.

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_one :user
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :username, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the format of the Post JSON to include the User association:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(only: [:id, :description, :created_at, :user_id],
    include: [user: { only: [:name] }]
      )
  end
```